# Locked ViewControllers in storyboard

Tags: xcode, locking, storyboard

I have one big storyboard with many viewControllers in it. But some of this viewControllers are locked. So I went to Identity inspector and found "Lock" parameter, but even if I select "Nothing", viewController does not unlock. 
So according to http://pragmapilot.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/xcode-5-interface-builder-storyboard-locked/ I tried change storyboard source code, but my storyboard already has this:

```
propertyAccessControl="none"
```

So it should be unlocked. How to unlock storyboard?

UPD: resolved!

Answer (score 0):

You should select inherited - (nothing) option.

Comment: Please check this property for your root View controller as well. 
see the link : http://pragmapilot.wordpress.com/2013/09/25/xcode-5-interface-builder-storyboard-locked/

its very much self explanatory. Hope i am helpful to you.

Comment: I have already read that (it is in my question). But in my situation rootViewController is already with this property. And other controllers too

Comment: Would you please briefly explain me the situation. I am not sure i understood your problem correctly.

Comment: Hi Maria, i really want to listen from you. I am awaiting your response. PLease let me help you.

Comment: Hi! The problem was in ViewController, not in storyboard. Thanks!